# AJAX call and set active class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make an AJAX call and set the active class at the same time when clicking on a list item to filter what is shown.
Sample html:

```
   <li class="active" id='tag' onclick="showRes(this.value)" value="1" >Tennis</li>
    <li id='tag' onclick="showRes(this.value)" value="2">Soccer</li>
```

I have the AJAX function:

```
function showRes(str) {

        if (str == "") {
       ...
       .... 
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getres.php?q="+s_val+"&t="+t_val+"&c="+c_val,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

And the click function to set the active class:

```
    var s_val;
    var t_val;  
    var c_val;      
    var make_button_active = function()
    {
      var siblings =($(this).siblings());       
      siblings.each(function (index)
        {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
      )     
      $(this).addClass('active');
      s_val = $("#popular li.active").attr('value');
      t_val = $("#locations li.active").attr('value');  
      c_val = $("#categories li.active").attr('value');                     
    }

    $(document).ready(
      function()
      {
        $(".links li").click(make_button_active);   
      }  
    )
```

It works, but requires two clicks to trigger the ajax. Is there a way I can combine the two so they run at once?

Comment: If you're using jQuery for the make_button_active function, why can't you just use it to make the AJAX call? Much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

1. Change your markup a bit, pass `li` element to event handler, remove repeating id's:

   ```
   <li class="active" onclick="showRes(this)" value="1" >Tennis</li>
   <li onclick="showRes(this)" value="2">Soccer</li>
   ```
2. Put call to `make_button_active` in the same handler:

   ```
   function showRes(el) {

       // call ajax
       if (el.value == "") {
           ...
           ...
           xmlhttp.open("GET", "getres.php?q=" + s_val + "&t=" + t_val + "&c=" + c_val, true);
           xmlhttp.send();
       }

       // call function
       make_button_active(el);      
   }
   ```
3. Simplify you `make_button_active` function a little:

   ```
   var make_button_active = function(el) {

       $(el).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

       s_val = $("#popular li.active").attr('value');
       t_val = $("#locations li.active").attr('value');  
       c_val = $("#categories li.active").attr('value');                     
   }
   ```
4. Remove this: `$(".links li").click(make_button_active);` from document ready handler.

Demo without ajax: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/zqteqr54/)

Comment: Thanks! The code works well - but I'm still having the issue of having to double-click to fire the ajax. i.e. the first click sets the li active, but I need to click again to update the results from ajax. Any thoughts? Could it have to do with my document ready handler?

Comment: In the demo it works with one click - try the third item.

Comment: The ajax is not called at all if `li` has something in `value` atttibute.

Comment: Ok - how would I go about getting it to work if there is a value? (As there always will be)

Comment: It was you initial condition to call ajax on empty value - see `if (str == "")` in your question. If you want to call ajax regardless of that - comment out  `if (el.value == "") {` and the closing bracket for that from my code. Or explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry it was late and got confused - ignore that last one. The ajax gets called in the 'else'. My issue is that when I click the "li" it sets it to active, but the ajax does not work until a second click. Example: I click tennis on my code is goes active; then I click soccer, it goes active, but the results show up for tennis

Comment: It depends on what you do with the ajax response. You should attach a callback to it and do whatever updates you need from there. Add it to your post so I can take a look. There was a good advice from @Mark Eriksson to use jQuery to call ajax as it would simplify things for you - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ or https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/.

Comment: Will take a look at that thanks - I moved 'make_button_active(el)' inside the ajax call and works now. Cheers.

Comment: Glad you solved that!